# Calculating Profit in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

This program is supposed to read in values from a text file and get a sum of all these values. It is then to use information gathered from a series of check boxes and text boxes to calculate the final profit.

As the code is written now, the profit is only correct if all check boxes are selected, but I need it to be correct if one, two, or all three are checked. Here is the current code
    Option Strict On

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim sum As Double
    Dim fileRead As Boolean
    Dim profit As Double

    Private Sub menOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menOpen.Click
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.Filter = "text files |*.txt|All Files|*.*"
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

        If ofd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim selectedFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName)
            If selectedFileName.ToLower = "profit.txt" Then
                Dim line As String
                Using reader As New StreamReader(ofd.OpenFile)
                    While Not reader.EndOfStream
                        line = reader.ReadLine
                        Dim value As Integer
                        If Integer.TryParse(line, value) Then
                            sum = sum + value
                            fileRead = True
                        End If
                        Console.WriteLine(line)
                    End While
                End Using
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot use that file!")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub menExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub radSales_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radSales.CheckedChanged
        If radSales.Checked Then
            profit = sum
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub radSandO_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radSandO.CheckedChanged
        If radSandO.Checked Then
            If Trim(txtWages.Text) = "" Then
               txtWages.Text = CStr(0)
            End If
            profit = (sum - CDbl(txtWages.Text) - CDbl(txtRent.Text) - CDbl(txtUtilities.Text))
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub menComputeProfit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menComputeProfit.Click
        If fileRead = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("The file profit.txt has not been read in yet, the profit will be set to zero.")
            sum = 0
        End If

        If chkWages.Checked Then
             profit = CDbl(("$" & Val(sum) - (Val(txtWages.Text) + Val(txtRent.Text) + Val(txtUtilities.Text))))
        End If
        If chkRent.Checked Then
            profit = CDbl(("$" & Val(sum) - (Val(txtRent.Text) + Val(txtWages.Text) + Val(txtUtilities.Text))))
        End If
        If chkUtilities.Checked Then
            profit = CDbl(("$" & Val(sum) - (Val(txtUtilities.Text) + Val(txtWages.Text) + Val(txtRent.Text))))
        End If

        txtAnswer.Text = profit.ToString

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I take it you have checked that the textboxes only contain numerics and decimal point.

Comment: Remember when calculating profit in VB.NET to take Micro$oft's wedge off!

Comment: I think your profit assignment is slightly wrong.  Try removing the "$" from the mix and prepend it to the string when assigned to the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of those text inputs is most likely empty (as the error states). Even if it wasn't empty, it could still be an invalid Double value.

In order to safely check if the string can be converted to a double, you can use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
If Double.TryParse(value, number) Then
  Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> {1}", value, number)
Else
  Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value)      
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the error all straightened out now. But I still cannot get the program to display the profit in the txtAnswer textbox. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you experiencing? Are there any error messages being shown or exceptions being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Before you convert a string to double, check that the string is not empty. This is what error says. Afterwards you should check that the string in the box is actually numeric.

Comment: Thanks, I have the error all straightened out now. But I still cannot get the program to display the profit in the txtAnswer textbox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are using TextChanged Event for txtAnswer

```
 Private Sub txtAnswer_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAnswer.TextChanged
    txtAnswer.Text = CStr(profit)
End Sub
```

So the above code is going to fire itself each time it changes! Just pop profit into txt Answer each time it is calculated

```
If chkWages.Checked Then
        profit = CDbl(("$" & Val(sum) - Val(txtWages.Text)))
        txtAnswer.text = profit
    End If
    If chkRent.Checked Then
        profit = CDbl(("$" & Val(sum) - Val(txtRent.Text)))
        txtAnswer.text = profit
    End If
    If chkUtilities.Checked Then
        profit = CDbl(("$" & Val(sum) - Val(txtUtilities.Text)))
        txtAnswer.text = profit
    End If
```

A bit untidy but that should do it... you will need to do this whenever profit changed. And get rid of the TextChanged event.

**UPDATED ANSWER FOR CLARITY**

Ok I never add currency symbols so I'm not sure what `CDbl(("$" & Val(Sum) - Val(txtWages.Text)))` will do as it may treat it as a string character "$" rather than a currency. 
Get rid of the "$" and just add the values... if you want to then stick the $ in front once calculation is complete say `txtAnswer = $ & profit.toString`

Comment: I ended up doing away with the sub dealing with the txtAnswer. I have updated the post with my current issue, any suggestions?

Comment: So where are you updating txtAnswer? I can't see any point in your code that will change it's value - see my last bit of code where I've added txtAnswer.text = profit

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm really tired and forgot that I hadn't updated the code since I have been working with it. I have edited the post to reflect the most recent code and the issue I'm having with it.

Comment: Ok I never add currency symbols so I'm not sure if CDbl(("$" & Val(Sum) - Val(txtWages.Text))) will do as it may treat it as a string character "$" rather than a currency. Get rid of the "$" and just add the values... if you want to then stick the $ in front once calculation is complete say txtAnswer = $ & profit.toString

Comment: I took out the currency symbol, but still not calculating the profit correctly.

Comment: As others have mentioned... you will need to check that all text boxes (txtWages, txtRent, txtUtilities) must be checked that thy contain a valid numeric value. They cannot be blank or contain text. If blank then change to 0.00... this is the only thing I can think that is creating the error your are reporting. If all your values are numeric that CDbl should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I am no longer getting that error message, but still cannot get the program to calculate the total profit correctly. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48676/discussion-between-mych-and-beth-tanner)